My SQL query (in Zoho Analytics) isn't working and I'm not sure why
Solved: I was using a reserved term 'USER' unknowingly.
For context, I'm very new to SQL. My goal in the script below is to combine multiple data tables into a single query table in Zoho Analytics. From this query table I will generate reports. The data in the source tables are already populated.
When I go to execute the query, I get a non-informative error from Zoho Analytics saying it doesn't support this query and no output.
Do you see anything wrong with my code?
SELECT
         SITE."name" as 'Site Name',
         SESSION."Id" as 'Session ID',
         SESSION."userId" as 'User ID',
         SESSION."status" as 'Status',
         SESSION."chargePointId" as 'ChargePoint ID',
         SESSION."amount" as "Value",
         SESSION."Calc - Energy [kWh]" as 'Energy',
         SESSION."Calc - Start Datetime" as 'Start',
         SESSION."Calc - End Datetime" as 'End',
         SESSION."Calc - Session Duration" as 'Session Duration',
         SESSION."Calc - Est. Charge Duration" as 'Charge Duration',
         SESSION."reason" as 'Termination Reason',
         CHARGER."tags_0" as 'Tags'
FROM "Sessions Table" AS  SESSION
JOIN "Chargers Table" AS  CHARGER ON SESSION."chargePointId" = CHARGER."id"
JOIN "Sites Table" AS  SITE ON CHARGER."locationId"  = SITE."id"
JOIN "Partners Table" AS PARTNER ON CHARGER."ownerPartnerID" = PARTNER."id"
JOIN "Users Table" AS USER ON SESSION."userID" = USER."id"
ORDER BY 'Session ID' DESC 

Here is the output I get from Zoho when I try to run it.

Error Details:
Your SQL Query is not supported in Zoho Analytics. If you wish to report this as a bug, send a screenshot of your query to support@zohoanalytics.com.


I'd try double quotes for all identifiers, i.e. column aliases too. E.g. as "Site Name". The ANSI SQL way.

looking at some online guidance it looks like SITE."name" should be "SITE"."name" (I'm not a zoho users, I've just looked online at some code samples)

Minimize the problem, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm

Thanks for the thought time. The issue was I was using a reserved term USER which was causing the issue with Zoho. Changing away from the reserved term fixed my issue.

USER is a reserved keyword. Put it in quotes.

Single or double? (OP has used both...)

This was it thank you for the fix. I changed it to USERS instead of USER and it worked. I didn't realize it was reserved. Many thanks.

You're welcome!
